# read \xHH escapes from file as raw binary in Python

Tags: python, file, raw-data

I have following problem:

I want to read from file into a raw binary string :

The file looks like this (with escape characters, not binary data):

> \xfc\xe8\x82\x00\x00\x00\x60\x89\xe5\x31\xc0\x64\x8b\x50\x30\x8b\x52

code used:

> data = open("filename", "rb").read()

result obtained:

> b"\\xfc\\xe8\\x82\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x60\\x89\\xe5\\x31\\xc0\\x64\\x8b\\x50\\x30\\x8b\\x52"

With dobule \ .

How can I read it as binary string like : `\xaa` characters ?
(Without escape characters)

Comment: Is your file the binary represented by what you're saying it looks like, or is it ascii that is *actually* what you're showing us, and you want to interpret it?

Comment: The string is being read correctly, backslashes are represented in python strings using '\\' escape sequence. When you print the unformatted string (with b"" prefix), the escape sequence characters are shown. Add more details to the question on how you are planning to use the string for more helpful answers

Comment: it is a simple txt file i should write that sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. Your problem here is that you're asking the wrong question. Your data file isn't a raw binary string, it's an encoded one, encoded with escape characters. You're reading it as a raw binary, though, when you need instead to decode the escapes. Try

```
data = open("filename", "r", encoding='unicode_escape').read().encode('raw_unicode_escape')
```

instead.

Edit: ok, this now works. You need to encode into raw_unicode_escape, not utf-8 (the default).

Comment: Yes my question is wrong sorry about that. But your solution works . Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This output *is OK*.

Python is *outputting* this data with double backslashes to show that it is *non-printable*. However, it's *stored* correctly, as bytes.

Comment: Not exactly, when i want to use it i got en error.
If i add in my code following: 
data = b"\xaa\xaa\xaa" Works but when i read it from file like above i got en error

Comment: @Symonen, __which one??__

Comment: don't confuse `b'\\xfc'` (4 bytes) and `b'\xfc'` (1 byte).

Answer (score 0):

To convert 4 ascii characters (`\` `x` `f` `c`) from file into a single byte (`252==0xfc`), you could read ascii characters as bytes (`data = open("filename", "rb").read()`), remove `\x` prefix and convert the resulting hexadecimal bytestring into `bytes` containing corresponding raw binary data:

```
>>> import binascii
>>> data = b'\\xfc\\xe8\\x82'
>>> binascii.unhexlify(data.replace(b'\\x', b''))
b'\xfc\xe8\x82'
```

It is best to avoid storing data as `b'\\xfc'` (4 bytes) instead of `b'\xfc'` (1 byte) in the first place.